# Golang test gives inconsistent results when ran in verbose mode

Tags: testing, go

I have a single test function in my _test.go file with a bunch of sub tests.
It looks like this:

```
func MyTest(t *testing.T) { 
    t.Run("Subtest1", func(t *testing.T) {
       ...
    })
    t.Run("Subtest2", func(t *testing.T) {
       ...
    })
}
```

I run the test with `go test` and get

```
PASS
ok      package_path    9.137s
```

However, I would like to see listed all my subtests in the result. Looking at the `Run` function in `$GOROOT/src/testing/testing.go` it looks like I need the test to be `chatty`.

So I tried to run the test via `go test -v` but I still do not get the desired output. Instead my test is now failing:

```
=== RUN   MyTest
api.test: error: expected argument for flag '-t', try --help
exit status 1
FAIL    package_path    0.004s
```

`--help` does not show anything about `-t`

Comment: pretty weird. does it work with `go test -v github.com/Jana/MyRepo/...`?

Comment: Can you confirm the same behavior with this simple example? https://gist.github.com/benjic/956cc4b7bd50d4b5f7dc229b73a7b1ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the code I was testing which expects its own arguments and contained this line:

```
kingpin.MustParse(cli.Parse(os.Args[1:]))
```

I know disallow parsing of arguments in the test.